# MySQLdb module for python 2.6.8

Tags: python

I need to use MySQLdb module for connecting to a MySQL database . But I don't know which version is compatible with my python version. I am using python 2.6.8. Could anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this link: It is compatible with 2.4 to 2.7

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5